# How to change our design or content that users open our website when they see the content?

Tags: website-design, search, hyperlinks, google, seo

**Maybe the title is not clear; Because the subject is a little special**

We are well ranked website and our users are really important for us, and we really care about them. We even don't advertise on our website or if we do we try to do our best design for ads and they have to has harmony with the entire website's template.
[image]

We have Chrome extension and Firefox add-on for our website that users out of our website can use our service and our extension is really popular and users like it. (We know this from feedback)

recently we developed a new Chrome extension; if you search for **"define computer"** or **"define something..."** Google will define it for you, see the below image:
[image]

And we just made something like what Google return for Persian (We are a big famous dictionary and more services) and when user is searching for something in Persian or just search a word we will show them the result inside Google by our extension and they don't need to open our website anymore if they see all the result inside Google (by out extension)! This is what we return:

[image]

We'll show what user search and we have it in our database inside Google search, Then we think more than half of our extension users won't open our website. (Just about 10% of our users will install this extension) but it is still a good number of users!

We really care about our users and like to let them use this extension because this extension will really help them but the problem is we also need our ranking.

So, what we are going to do is just show half of the result and put a **read more** link, Show some more words that user may be interested to know what does they mean and click and open the website...

Any suggestion? Your advises would be so useful for us

Comment: Let me see if I've got this right... You made an extension that doesn't require visiting your site to get the benefit of your site, but now you want users to use that extension AND visit your site so you retain traffic counts/ranking, despite only 10% of your users using this advanced feature. Have I got that right?

Comment: @Confused yes; Until now the first version on our extension users are just 10% of our users. And we want two thing 1-Give good free service to users 2-We also need our ranking and page view

Comment: Do you offer an [OS X custom dictionary](http://blog.nagpals.com/mac-dictionaries/), too? Anyway, what do you really need the ranking and page views for? For page views in particular, what’s different if viewed directly in a browser from when embedded into another page by the browser extension?

Comment: @Crissov We are a famous dictionary website and we need our ranking because ranking is important to say we are working on our website. People care about ranking and we need to earn money to work on our website and develop it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a user point of view, they're going to get this:

**Performant, Efficient Extension Experience**

**vs**

**Contrivances Creating Web Traffic Ranking**

When these two things are at odds with each other, you have to favour good service over ranking and page views, and find another way to get gain from the usage of your extension.

You will greatly annoy anyone benefitting from the streamlined efficiencies in operation and performance of the extension if you attempt to contort it for gain at the expense of user fluidity of experience. Any link, load, etc not in the reason for the fastness and utility of the extension should not be added for the benefit of your traffic as it will compromise the designed intent of the extension.

Find another way to benefit from use of the extension that does NOT compromise the users and the stated and designed purpose of the extension.

Comment: So; What do you think? This extension would be harmful for the feather of our website? What happens if 50% of our users like to use it!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm catching your drift. Perhaps some more details. And then, as I say, start thinking about how to profit from the extension without being an arsehole to your users.